# How to pass a data from laravel into Vue Router?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using laravel-vue project
and i want to pass the base url from laravel view to vue router component.
ex. this data  {{ url('/') }}.
Is this possible to pass it on the vue router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a JS global variable in your Blade file and then retrieves it from the router.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.routerBaseURL = 'something';
</script>
```

```js
new VueRouter({
    base: window.routerBaseURL,
    ...
});
```